# Should you call pushState when an ajax request is sent or recieved?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html5-history

When dealing with the HTML5 history API and loading page parts with AJAX, should the `pushState()` call be made when the AJAX request is sent, or in the callback function that processes the AJAX response?

Since AJAX is asynchronous, two AJAX link clicks within a short time span could return the requested page parts in either order (resulting in the response callback functions firing in either order). When dealing with multiple panes and possibly slower connections, *when* the request gets saved to history could make a difference in intuitive user experience.

Are there any best practices on when during the AJAX life-cycle the `pushState()` method should be called?